# Inline-block + min/max-width behavior

Tags: html, css

I see in many browsers (FF,Opera,Ie) that elements I give them "inline-block" and "min/max width" , their width is  automatically sets to "min-width", and not max-width, as expected.
Is that normal behavior?

Can I solve it in css way (inline-block element with max-width)?
(I know about floats/tables/js, there are some reasons i need do it in this way)

[here is the code](http://cssdesk.com/yBTUN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering a valid behavior. `min-width` means that the width cannot be less than the `min-width` value. On the other hand, `max-width` means that the width cannot exceed the `max-width` value (but it can be less). Thus if you specify both `min-width` and `max-width` on an empty element, its width is set to `min-width`.

Comment: It happens just to inline-block elements, they get min-width when max-width is possible and expected (in block elements it works normally).

Comment: In the example you posted, even block elements are set to min-width as expected. max-width is applied only if the width of the element is greater than the max-width value.

Comment: in my example width of #main_wrapper is 300px,not 200px

Comment: The reason why #main_wrapper is set to max-width is the default width behavior of div - by default, divs have 100% width and this width is then clamped by max-width. This is not true for inline-block elements which have the width specified by their content, which means that there the min-width property is applied. Still, the behavior is correct.