# How can I make div's line up and be resizeable according to the browser size

Tags: html, css

So if I take a div and add this to it:

```
<div class="dongs">test</div>
<div class="dongs">test</div>
<div class="dongs">test</div>

.dongs {
 background-color: blue;
 max-width: 500px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

It will make the div's line up beside each other with a blue background BUT the max width will 
appear to not be working for some reason.

The reason why I need max-width to work is because if I have those beside each other and lets say
a user comes a long with a small browser it will resize the div's and squish them in so that they
are smalled which is what max-width does. Allows the container to become smaller but not larger.

However, if I remove the inline-block; the div's wont be next to each other BUT the max-width
will work and they will resize. Please, I need help. Thanks

EDIT: I did research a lot but cannot seem to find the answer. I did see one  stackoverflow post but
it did not make sense to me and didnt help. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331882/inline-block-min-max-width-behavior)

Comment: Are you looking for `min-width` instead of `max-width`?

Comment: I need max-width so that I can make the div expand to 500 pixels but if the browser is too small it scales it down from 500 pixels to less. Min width will just keep it at the minimum width without scaling it which will result in a small browser stacking the div's and becoming ugly.

Comment: Try to google about [media-queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width). It helps you identify the browser width and you can use different CSS..

Comment: @user3003216 ill look into it as that will help in a lot of areas

Comment: When you say max width is not working, can you explain more on what exactly is happening unexpectedly. When try that code in fiddle the max-width seems to be working fine.

Comment: Hmm.. Max-width is suppose to maximize the width but allow the width to become smaller. I just tried it in JSFiddle and it didnt work. It did not max out the width to 500px instead it just kept it the same. Now, in JSFiddle try changing max-width to just width and you will see it go to 500px but its unable to resize down to a smaller size. Max-width: http://prntscr.com/4256dp Width:http://prntscr.com/4256fr

Comment: That is as expected. When you assign a `width` you are instructing the browser to allocate that much width for the element. But when you do `max-width` you are instructing the browser to allocate only a maximum of that much width at all times. It means the width can go up to 500 but not beyond. If the content is less it will be lesser than 500.

Comment: Try adding some extra content to the div (such that it needs more than 500px) and you would see that with `max-width` the box size stops at 500px and doesn't go beyond whereas with just `width` it keeps expanding to fit the contents.

Comment: @Harry Yeah thats what I want, I want the width to be maximized to 500px but for some reason it doesnt maximize the div's even though there is enough screen size left and if you remove the inline-block it all of a sudden works. I need it to work with inline-block so that the div's line up.

Comment: @Harry yeah that works! But the issue is If I have status box's at the top I want them to be the same size. like this: http://prntscr.com/4257r3 but if 1 div has 1 number but the other div as like 5 numbers they will be different size's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57218/discussion-between-harry-and-user3728587).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the below code:

```
.dongs {
    background-color: blue;
    max-width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Explanation:** Since we are not setting any explicit width at start, the browser will assign the minimum width required to fit the contents of the element for all the elements (like you can see for the 2nd and 3rd div's the width is different based on content). However, setting the `max-width: 33%` means that the browser at any point of time would only allocate a maximum of 1/3rd of the parent element's (or body if no other parent) width to this element. So, if the content is anything more it would start wrapping around.

You would also want to set either `overflow: hidden;` or  `word-wrap: break-word;` in addition. The first makes the overflowing content get hidden (would be helpful when they are very lengthy words) while the second break's lengthy words and then wraps it around to the next lines. Either one can be used depending on the needs.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/7GZqu/) | [**W3C Spec for Min/Max Width**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you haven't specify the actual width, and instead of using `display: inline-block`, it would be better to use `float: left` and add some margin if you need any space between those div. But, don't forget to change the width property.

Check out my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KMvr/)...